# EJS JSON Parsing

Tags: html, node.js, json, parsing, ejs

So this is the [html](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/GpdgF/) I want to have generated dynamically by an array. I am not sure if this is the best method for Ejs in Nodejs, if not I'll be happy to receive your alternative way of doing it! The JSON looks like that:

```
                      {'TOP':{
                              'title':"TOP1",
                              'SUBTOP':{
                                        'title':"SUBTOP1",
                                        'article':{'title':'Article','link':'#'}
                                      },
                              'SUBTOP':{
                                        'title':"SUBTOP2",
                                        'article':{'title':'Article','link':'#'},
                                        'SUBSUBTOP':{
                                                  'title':"SUBSUBTOP2",
                                                  'SUBSUBSUBTOP':{ 
                                                                'title':"SUBSUBSUBTOP2",
                                                                'article':{'title':'Article','link':'#'},
                                                                'article':{'title':'Article','link':'#'}
                                                              },
                                                  'article':{'title':'Article','link':'#'},
                                                  'article':{'title':'Article','link':'#'}
                                                  },
                                        'article':{'title':'Article','link':'#'}
                                      }

                            }

                      },
                      {'TOP':{
                              'title':"TOP2",
                              'article':{'title':'Article','link':'#'},
                              'article':{'title':'Article','link':'#'}
                            }

                      }
                    ]`
```

Unfortunately, I am too incompetent to solve this problem because I don't know how to parse the JSON... This is the code I got so far:

```
<ul>
    <% for(var i in navtree) { %>
    <p>
        <h2><%= navtree[i]['TOP']['title'] %></h2>
        <h2><%= navtree[i]['TOP']['SUBTOP'] %></h2>
    </p>

    <% } %>

</ul>
```

May somebody has any advise for me? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply parse (using `JSON.parse(object)`) it server-side, before rendering?